# Display variable content, not variable name in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string-interpolation

I want to customize a message where from the back end the user can modify a Welcome Message. Something like:

> Welcome to #{userInfo["name"]}, out latest member

Where `userInfo["name"]` is a GET Variable.

I store this message on a model column called `welcomeMsj`.

Then I am trying to display the message using the model. Something like:

```
messages = Model.first

puts messages.welcomeMessage
```

I have an output like:

```
Welcome to #{userInfo["name"]}, out latest member
```

But I want to display:

> Welcome to Emmanuel, out latest member

What's the correct syntax for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using `erb` in your view?

Answer (score 1):

The [Liquid template engine](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid) was created just for this kind of use case.  You could have the backend user include a special string in double curly braces such as `{{name}}` that you then populate at render time.  For example, the backend user would set the welcome message to "`Welcome to {{name}}, our latest member.`" which would be stored in your database.  Assuming that the `current_user` variable represents the user that's currently logged in, you could render the customized message with the following code:

```
template = Liquid::Template.parse(messages.welcomeMessage) 
template.render('name' => current_user.name)
```

Another, more dangerous strategy is to use `eval` which will interpret the string as code:

```
puts eval("\"" + messages.welcomeMessage + "\"")
```

This isn't recommended because it could allow a malicious user to run arbitrary code.  By using Liquid, you maintain control of the exact value that gets used in place of `{{name}}`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Welcome to <%= userInfo["name"] %>, our latest member
```

Comment: This wouldn't automagically work, though. The other part of the solution is missing.